# Call to undefined function w3tc_cache_get() in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, custom-wordpress-pages, w3-total-cache

I am trying to use the w3tc_cache_get() function to get cached data in WordPress. However, I am getting the error message "Call to undefined function w3tc_cache_get()".

I have checked the following:

- The W3 Total Cache plugin is activated and the caching feature is enabled.
- The w3tc_cache_get() function is inside a specific file which I included in my theme's functions.php file using "require" method.
- The version of WordPress I am using is 6.2.2.
- The version of the W3 Total Cache plugin I am using is the latest version.

```
    <?php
    // Set the expiration time for the cached data.
    define('WP_ROCKET_CACHE_EXPIRY', 60 * 60);


    // Enable caching for dynamic content.
    add_filter('w3tc_cache_dynamic', '__return_true');


    // Function to fetch data from an API.
    function fetch_api_data($api_url) {

        $api_response = wp_remote_get($api_url);

        if (wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($api_response) === 200) {

            return json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($api_response));

        } else {

            return array();
        
        }
    }


    function cache_api_data($api_url, $data) {

        $cache_key = 'api_data_' . $api_url;

        w3tc_cache_set($cache_key, $data, 'default', W3TC_CACHE_EXPIRY);
    }


    function get_cached_data ($api_url) {

        $cache_key = 'api_data_'.$api_url;

        $cached_data = w3tc_cache_get($cache_key, 'default');

        if ($cached_data !== null) return $cached_data;

        return [];

    }



    function get_api_data ($api_url = "localhost/api/v1/temp_name") {

        $cached_data = get_cached_data ($api_url);

        if ( !empty($cached_data) ) return $cached_data;
    
        $api_response = fetch_api_data ($api_url);

        cache_api_data ($api_url, $api_response);

        return $api_response;

    }
```

Basically, I want to get data from an API and store it in the cache. This way, whenever I need to get data from the API, I can call the get_api_data() function, which will check if the data is already cached. If the data is cached, the function will return the cached data. If the data is not cached, the function will fetch the data from the API and store it in the cache.

Comment: Very unclear what the execution context is here. Where does this `get_api_data` function get called?

Comment: Also, where is the code you have shown us, located? Is that part of a plugin?

Comment: Basically, I want to get data from an API and store it in the cache. This way, whenever I need to get data from the API, I can call the get_api_data() function, which will check if the data is already cached. If the data is cached, the function will return the cached data. If the data is not cached, the function will fetch the data from the API and store it in the cache.

Comment: That explains what you want to achieve, but doesn't actually answer either of the two questions I asked you.

Comment: (Not sure I'd implement this so that it relies on any 3rd-party caching plugin to begin with. WP Transients are good for stuff like this.)

Comment: This code is located in function.php file of the theme and I'm calling it inside the index.php file inside the theme folder. I'm using W3 Total Cache plugin to perform this tasks and "w3tc_cache_set" is the function provided by that plugin.

Comment: Not sure what purpose the index.php inside the theme folder is supposed to have to begin with, but it sounds like it might not actually have included the functions.php by that point - otherwise, if the functions.php required the file that contains the function, you should not be getting _that_ error. (Not sure if you might get additional errors after that - just including a file that contains some function definitions, doesn't necessarily mean the rest of the plugin context has properly initialized.)